# Bulk insert doesn't import every row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have a CSV file with 1048576 rows. I have to import the data into my SQL Server table. I used bulk insert to import; after executing that query SQL shows 1048576 rows are affected, but in my table, only 999999 rows are filled. Other rows disappeared and no remaining values. Why? My code is given below.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.TT32CU
FROM 'C:\CZGTECH\DATABASE\ttcu.CSV'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Comment: Does COUNT(1) on the table also result in 999999?

Comment: Strange, I cannot explain

Comment: could you suggest any method for importing excl.csv into dB table?

Comment: when am used COUNT(1) 2097156 and message is no column name @HoneyBadger

Comment: No column name is correct, unless you give an alias (`select count(1) cnt`, for example). Did you perhaps try the bulk insert twice? Because 2097156 is double the number of records in your .csv. If so, the bulk insert probably did work correctly, but there might be a limitation on the number of records management studio is showing.

Comment: is there any limitation on sql server 2014 management studio? if I recreate the database n table, will it work?  @HoneyBadger

Comment: I am not aware of any such limitation, I've had many results with over 1m rows. This might be different between different edition of sql server management studio though, Whether it will work is difficult to say from here. I'd say try and test, if a `count(1)` results in the correct number it did work, if it also returns 999999 it didnt (in which case I wouldn't know why).